# BizTalk xml file to a flatfile format

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

Relatively new to BizTalk; I could use seasoned help.

I'm faced with having to try to map a source XML document to a flat-file TAB delimited destination.  My source document has some nested nodes that I need to iterate through and translate them each as a row on the flat-file document; classic sales order header/detail relationship. The results would need me to repeat the header information for every nested element in the child node.

I've tried a solution using a looping functoid but I'm not sure how to represent the destination list correctly. Am I missing the obvious? At what destination row element should I link my "Looping" output param to?

For demonstration sake here's an example of the schemas I'm working with.

SOURCE SCHEMA  (Don't have the possibility to modify the source structure)

- schema\
- salesorders\
- salesorders\orders\
- orders\soid
- orders\cust name
- orders\address
- orders\detail\
- orders\detail\msrp
- orders\detail\modelno
- orders\detail\sku

DESTINATION SCHEMA

- schema\
- \root\
- soid
- custname
- address
- etc...

Flat file OUTPUT (One line per detail item)

- soid  custname  address  msrp  modelno  sku
- soid  custname  address  msrp  modelno  sku

Anybody could orient me in right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You'll link your Looping Functoid from the source node you want to have generate a new record to (usually) the outer-record node (usually first child of the Root, but not always) of the destination.  This will basically tell the map "Every time you see a new `blah` in my source, create a whole new record in my destination."

Comment: Hi, thank-you for answering.

I've attempted to link source "salesorders\orders" node to my "looping" functoid and then the functoid to the first child of the record.  I still am not able to reproduce x number of lines per x number of child elements.  

So basically referring to my sample schemas;  I drag/drop orders/soid to my functoid and then drag/drop a connection from the functoid to node \root\soid. 

No luck :(

Comment: is your destination schema set up for a looping structure?  Remember that in the Schema, the Root refers (more or less) to the file.  So based on what I'm seeing you have a single record schema there.  What I would expect is a Child Record of Root called 'Order' which would then have child elements/attributes of SOID, custName, etc.  'Order' would be set to Min Occurs = 1, Max Occurs = Unbounded.  You'd then hook your looping functoid to the 'Order' node.